# Laravel 'sudo: no tty' error on Artisan::call when clearing cache from varnish

Tags: linux, laravel, ssh, sudo, tty

I followed this [Git repo](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-varnish)

Everything worked fine.

I can be able to issue `php artisan varnish:flush` from SSH.

but when I tried to flush cache from script i was getting error as

**sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified**

This is how I added in routes.php

```
Route::get('/flush', function() {
    Artisan::call('varnish:flush');
});
```

and I also Tried

```
Route::get('/flush', function() {
    (new Spatie\Varnish\Varnish())->flush();
});
```

This is how complete error looks.

```
ProcessFailedException in Varnish.php line 64:
The command "sudo varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T 127.0.0.1:6082 'ban req.http.host ~ (^www.host.com$)'" failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: /home/admin/web/host.com/public_html

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I am using Vesta CP Over VPS.

Find Me A Solution to solve this error..

Answer (score 1):

When using `sudo` the command opens the folder `/dev/tty` for read-write and prints that error if it fails.

Rebooting your machine would be sufficient to get the folder back if it was removed. The system recreates all devices in /dev during bootup.

Also, make sure the permissions are correct:

`chmod 666 /dev/tty`